# Uknown nginx Error Messages

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, backend

I am getting some nginx errors as I can see them in my error.log which I am unable to understand. They look like:

ERRORS:

```
2011/03/13 21:48:21 [crit] 14555#0:
*323314343 open() "/usr/local/nginx/proxy_temp/0/95/0000000950" failed (13: Permission denied) while reading upstream, client: XX.XX.XX.XX, server: , request: "GET /abc.jpg 2 HTTP/1.0", upstream: "http://192.168.162.141:80/abc.jpg", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://domain.com"

2011/03/13 22:00:07 [crit] 14552#0:
*324171134 open() "/usr/local/nginx/proxy_temp/1/95/0000000951" failed (13: Permission denied) while reading upstream, client: XX.XX.XX.XY, server: , request: "GET mno.png HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://192.168.162.141:80/mno.png", host: "example.com", referrer: "http://domain2.com"
```

I also looked at these locations but found that there is no file by this name.

```
root@li235-57:/var/log/nginx# /usr/local/nginx/proxy_temp/1/ 00/ 01/ 02/ 03/ 04/ 05/ 06/ 07/ 08/ 09/ 10/ 11/ 12/ 13/ 14/ 15/ 16/ 17/ 18/ 19/ 20/ 21/ 22/ 23/ 24/ 25/ 26/ 27/ 28/ 29/ 30/ 31/ 32/ 33/ 34/ 35/ 36/ 37/ 

root@li235-57:/var/log/nginx# ls /usr/local/nginx/proxy_temp/0/ 01/ 02/ 03/ 04/ 05/ 06/ 07/ 08/ 09/ 10/ 11/ 12/ 13/ 14/ 15/ 16/ 17/ 18/ 19/ 20/ 21/ 22/ 23/ 24/ 25/ 26/ 27/ 28/ 29/ 30/ 31/ 32/ 33/ 34/ 35/ 36/ 37/
```

Can someone help me whats going on / how can I debug this more and better fix this

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://derekneely.com/2009/06/nginx-failed-13-permission-denied-while-reading-upstream/ as he seems to have gotten the same issue as you and found a fix.